# libGLEW.so.1.11: cannot open shared object file

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking

I am trying to compile an opengl program which results in:

> error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.11: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

compile:

```
 g++ -o triangle triangle.cpp LoadShaders.cpp -I/home/mks/myGL/oglpg/include/ -L/home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib  -L/usr/lib64 -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW
```

In /home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib there are all the libraries:

```
 libGLEW.so       libGLEW.so.1.11.0  
 libGLEW.a    libGLEW.so.1.11
```

( I am not superuser , so I installed glew on the above folder )

If I do:

```
ldd ./triangle | grep "GLEW"
        libGLEW.so.1.11 => not found
```

--UPDATE ---

Compiling:

```
g++ -o triangle triangle.cpp LoadShaders.cpp -I/home/mks/myGL/oglpg/include/ -L/home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib -L/usr/lib64 -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW
```

ldd ./triangle :

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  
        libglut.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3 
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.1 
        libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1 
        libGLEW.so.1.11 => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6
        libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 
        libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 
        libnvidia-tls.so.340.29 => /usr/lib64/nvidia/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.29 
        libnvidia-glcore.so.340.29 => /usr/lib64/nvidia/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.29 
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6
```

ls -al /home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib :

```
drwxr-xr-x.  .
drwxr-xr-x.  ..
-rw-r--r--.  freeglut_static.lib
-rw-r--r--.  freeglut_static_vs2010_d.lib
-rw-r--r--.  freeglut_static_vs2010.lib
-rw-r--r--.  gl3w.c
-rw-r--r--.  glew_static_d.lib
-rw-r--r--.  glew_static_vs2010_d.lib
-rw-r--r--.  glew_static_vs2010.lib
-rw-r--r--.  libfreeglut.a
-rw-r--r--.  libglew32.a
-rw-r--r--.  libGLEW.a
lrwxrwxrwx.  libGLEW.so -> libGLEW.so.1.11.0
lrwxrwxrwx.  libGLEW.so.1.11 -> libGLEW.so.1.11.0
-rw-r--r--.  libGLEW.so.1.11.0
-rw-r--r--.  LoadShaders.cpp
-rw-r--r--.  targa.cpp
-rw-r--r--.  vbm.cpp
-rw-r--r--.  vermilion32_d.lib
-rw-r--r--.  vermilion32.lib
-rw-r--r--.  vermilion64_d.lib
-rw-r--r--.  vermilion64.lib
```

echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin:/home/mks/bin:/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin:/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: This is not a compile-time problem, but a run-time problem, as @Gilles explained.  You compiled the source code properly, now you need to point the run-time linker to the libraries that you linked against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instruct your system where to find dynamic libraries. System-wide directories like `/usr/lib` are in the default search path for dynamic libraries, but if you want to add custom directories, you need to declare them by listing them in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This is a colon-separated list of directories, like `PATH`.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib
```

Put this line in your `~/.profile` or wherever you define environment variables. You can also run it in a shell and it'll apply to all programs started from that shell.

Alternatively, when you build a program using the library, register its location on your system.

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib … -L /home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib -lGLEW
```

The [chapter on shared libraries in the Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) may be of additional help.

Comment: Using `RPATH` to link against external libraries (like you are doing in this case) may make the compiled binary less portable.  I think using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is the better solution in this case.

Comment: @jayhendren A binary produced using RPATH and copied to another machine will only work if the library is at the same location on the other machine (or more precisely in one of the same set of locations). If it doesn't work, you'll have to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the other machine, which you'd have to do anyway. RPATH is only a problem when you have multiple versions of the same library in different directories, and you want to pick a particular one whose location is different on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Just noticed the superuser comment. You can still try the link command without being root. There is the chance that the permissions for that folder will still allow you. If it fails then you will need to contact your SysAdmin for help.

---

Where the application is looking for the library, the symlink doesn't exist.

Try this (while root):

`ln -sf /home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib/libGLEW.so.1.11.0 /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.11`

After that run `ldd ./triangle` again and see if the output finds the symlink. If it doesn't look at the locations it is looking for the other symlinks and create a link there. If the location is not `/usr/lib64` then make sure you `unlink /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.11` after you correct the symlink locations so you don't leave a unused symlink on your filesystem and forget to clean it up later.

**ln** => Create link

**sf** => symlink, forced

Comment: :Unfortunatelly,the ln -sf doesn't work without being superuser.But ,I can't understand why it doesn't work since I have libGLEW.so.1.11 , and especially (libGLEW.so.1.11 -> libGLEW.so.1.11.0) in my home folder (/home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib)

Comment: Because when 'triangle' was built, the path specified for libGLEW was something else (/usr/lib64?) and not the your path. If you can recompile 'triangle' and change the path, it should work. Where is triangle looking for the other paths? Show the full out put of `ldd ./triangle` without the grep please.

Comment: :Ok , I updated.the libGLEW is only in my home folder.I tried also compiling without /usr/lib64

Comment: can you also provide the output of `ls -al /home/mks/myGL/oglpg/lib` to verify libGlew is linked properly in your build directory.  Also the contents of `PATH`

Comment: @eyoung100:Ok ,i updated

Comment: Sorry, been having net troubles.  Since everything is in the proper place the  Library Directive Line is what's screwing you up. Can you compile all the OpenGL libraries `-lglut -lGL -lGLU` in a subdirectory of your own home folder then pass `-L /home/some/subdirectory` instead of `/usr/lib/64` Otherwise have your SysAdmin install the package that contains libGlew.